# Git pull and push shows commits of other users as my commits

Tags: git, push

I committed my local changes and before doing a git push, did a git pull from origin master and then did a git push. However I see other's commits (different files that I didn't touch at all) as part of my commit log. Is there a way to exclude those files committed by others as part of my commit log? Or is it fine to go ahead and create a PR (and still exclude the unwanted files to be merged?)

Thanks

Comment: Please give exact commands. Is the other history diverged from your commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced the same issue, the small mistake you might have made is you are comparing your branch with an incorrect branch. ie you created a branch named feature/test that needs to be merged with the branch "develop" instead you are comparing with master branch. check this.its not recomended to raise PR if your seeing some changes you haven't made.

Answer (score 0):

> However I see other's commits (different files that I didn't touch at
>   all) as part of my commit log.

This is expected, because when you do `git push` or `git pull --rebase`, you merge commits from target branch into your local branch or rebase your changes on top of those commits respectively.

> Or is it fine to go ahead and create a PR (and still exclude the
>   unwanted files to be merged?)

When you create a pull request, changes shown in it are commits which are missing in target branch (e.g. those you have added). Therefore only files affected by your commits will be shown.